# Method Names for Operator Methods in C#

Tags: c#, operators, operator-overloading

Does anyone have a exhaustive list of the names that C#/CLR gives to operators? (Maybe my lack of sleep is kicking in, but I can't seem to find it on Google) E.g. op_Addition, op_Subtraction. Furthermore is there any chance that these would be different in other cultures?

I am trying to create a class that can add/subtract etc. two objects and I have done all the primitives - I just need to do the 'rest'.

Many thanks.

Comment: This is covered more fully in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016429/reflection-and-operator-overloads-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the full list of [C# overloadable operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators)

You can find a list of the operator Metadata/Generated MSIL names under [Framework Design Guidelines -> Operator Overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/operator-overloads).

There is a different [F# operator overload list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/operator-overloading#overloaded-operator-names).

Finally, refer to [ECMA-335 Common Language
Infrastructure (CLI)](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) I.10.3 Operator overloading, where the operators for C++/CLI are listed.

Comment: I know, but I need the actual method names in the final assembly, like op_Addition... Maybe I will go implement them all and reflect.

Comment: Jonathan, I believe the new link above has what you want.

Comment: Dang! The link is no longer active. I wonder where I can get this list now?

Answer (score 8):

Based on the *Expression* class:

```
== op_Equality
!= op_Inequality
>  op_GreaterThan
<  op_LessThan
>= op_GreaterThanOrEqual
<= op_LessThanOrEqual
&  op_BitwiseAnd
|  op_BitwiseOr
+  op_Addition
-  op_Subtraction
/  op_Division
%  op_Modulus
*  op_Multiply
<< op_LeftShift
>> op_RightShift
^  op_ExclusiveOr
-  op_UnaryNegation
+  op_UnaryPlus
!  op_LogicalNot
~  op_OnesComplement
   op_False
   op_True
++ op_Increment
-- op_Decrement
```

Comment: Is it possible to use these with `nameof()`?

Comment: @AaronFranke No, operators cannot be referenced directly.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is good because it links to a list of overloadable operators, but it doesn't strictly answer the question because it doesn't provide the names of the operators when they are compiled.

The runner up answer includes that, but it is an incomplete list and not well organized. For completeness' sake, I made my own list, including a few operators that you might expect to be overloadable but that aren't. The list is in order of operator precedence, from highest (tightest) priority to lowest.

```
Outside of Order of Operations (used when necessary to coerce types)
   op_Implicit
   op_True
   op_False

Unary (only one operator)
++ op_Increment (Includes preincrement and postincrement)
-- op_Decrement (Includes predecrement and postdecrement)
-  op_UnaryNegation
+  op_UnaryPlus
!  op_LogicalNot
~  op_OnesComplement
   op_Explicit
await (Not overloadable)

Multiplicative
/  op_Division
%  op_Modulus
*  op_Multiply

Additive
+  op_Addition
-  op_Subtraction

Shift
<< op_LeftShift
>> op_RightShift

Relational
>  op_GreaterThan
<  op_LessThan
>= op_GreaterThanOrEqual
<= op_LessThanOrEqual
as (Not overloadable)
is (Not overloadable)

Equality
== op_Equality
!= op_Inequality

And
&  op_BitwiseAnd

Exclusive Or
^  op_ExclusiveOr

Inclusive Or
|  op_BitwiseOr

Conditional And
&& (Not overloadable - use "implicit operator bool" or "operator true")

Contional Or
|| (Not overloadable - use "implicit operator bool" or "operator true")

Null-Coalescing Operator
?? (Not overloadable)

Ternary
?: (Not overloadable - use "implicit operator bool" or "operator true")

Assignment
=  (Not overloadable - for combined operator and assignment (such as +=), just use the operator (+))
```

Note: The C# compiler prefers `implicit operator bool` instead of the True and False operators, if both are defined.

According to a referenced [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016429/reflection-and-operator-overloads-in-c-sharp?lq=1), the following method names are also emitted/understood by the C# compiler, but

- I have run tests in Visual Studio 2015 and C#6.0 attempting to get these to work, and
- The C#5.0 spec lists the "complete set of unary [and binary] operator function names" (Appendix A, page 469) and these appear nowhere therein.

```
Unary
&   op_AddressOf
*   op_PointerDereference

Binary
.   op_MemberSelection
->  op_PointerToMemberSelection

    op_SignedRightShift
    op_UnsignedRightShift

=   op_Assign
*=  op_MultiplicationAssignment
/=  op_DivisionAssignment
%=  op_ModulusAssignment
-=  op_SubtractionAssignment
+=  op_AdditionAssignment
<<= op_LeftShiftAssignment
>>= op_RightShiftAssignment
|=  op_ExclusiveOrAssignment
&=  op_BitwiseAndAssignment
|=  op_BitwiseOrAssignment

    op_UnsignedRightShiftAssignment
    op_SignedRightShiftAssignment

,   op_Comma
```

Comment: That's really interesting, I guess these operator names are understood because of C++/CLI. I have checked the IL of a mixed mode assembly recently, and these names are used for classes compiled to managed code.

Answer (score 0):

This website gives the list of names for C# operators, displaying the operator, Action (name), Example & Result: [C# Operator List](http://techmantium.com/c-operator-list/)