# Reference operators in XML documentation

Tags: c#, .net, xml-documentation

I would like to reference an operator in a `<see cref="..." />` [XML documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) tag, but I can't seem to find any hints on how to do it. The [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx) on this tag only shows a simple example referencing a method, but does not go over different types of members that can be referenced.

In particular, I would like to reference an **implicit conversion operator**, but general rule for referencing operators will also be appreciated.

---

## Example

Let's say we have a simple structure for which we define `==`, `!=` and implicit conversion operators:

```
public struct MyStructure
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public static bool operator ==(MyStructure x, MyStructure y) => x.Value == y.Value;

    public static bool operator !=(MyStructure x, MyStructure y) => x.Value != y.Value;

    public static implicit operator MyStructure(int i) => new MyStructure { Value = i };
}
```

Simply enough one can reference the `Value` property with `<see cref="MyStructure.Value" />`, but how to go about referencing the `==` operator? I obviously tried `<see cref="MyStructure.==" />` and `<see cref="MyStructure.==(MyStructure, MyStructure)" />` but I don't think this works as it should because of these two observations:

1. The operator is not coloured in the tooltip showing a summary as opposed to other members being coloured when properly referenced
2. The *Go to definition* command does not work whereas it does for other properly referenced members

I also suspect tools like [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) used to generate *HTML* pages based on the *XML documentation* would not produce valid hyperlinks either, but that remains to be confirmed.

**EDIT**

I just confirmed that *Sandcastle* does not produce valid hyperlinks for any of my attempts. Also, when the option to generate the *XML documentation* in the project properties is checked, a warning with code ***CS1584*** is shown saying "*XML comment has syntactically incorrect cref attribute 'MyStructure.=='*".

---

## Justification

In case someone is wondering why do I want to reference an operator the answer is I am writing a unit test method performing tests on an operator and as a general rule I put references to tested members in the *XML documentation* for the test method. So what I'm after is this:

```
/// <summary>
/// This method performs tests regarding <see cref="..." /> operator
/// </summary>
[TestMethod]
public void ImplicitConversionOperator() { ... }
```

Comment: From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsbx0t7x.aspx), it looks like you can use: `<see cref="M:MyStructure.Operator==(a,b)"/>`. I tried it and it compiles w/o warning...and makes it into the XML.  IDE behavior is still incomplete.

Comment: @Clay You're right about the warning being gone, but unfortunately other concerns are still unresolved. It seems that putting `M:` in front (or any other letter followed by colon) lets you put almost anything after it without the warning - e.g. `<see cref="x:whatever"/>` does not raise the warning. Strangely enough,  two letters and a colon does not fly...

Comment: Yeah - I was playing with it. Seems like `M` means maybe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm on VS 2015 Enterprise...dunno 'bout other editions. It looks like, if you document your operator, you get full-on correct behavior:

```
/// <summary>The name sez it all</summary>
public struct MyStruct
{
  /// <summary>implicit</summary>
  /// <param name="i">an int</param>
  public static implicit operator MyStruct( int i )
  {
    return new MyStruct( );
  }
  /// <summary>Thus and so</summary>
  public static bool operator ==( MyStruct a, MyStruct b )
  {
    return false;
  }

  /// <summary>Thus and so</summary>
  public static bool operator !=( MyStruct a, MyStruct b )
  {
    return true;
  }

  /// <summary>Thus and so</summary>
  public override bool Equals( object obj )
  {
    return base.Equals( obj );
  }

  /// <summary>Thus and so</summary>
  public override int GetHashCode( )
  {
    return base.GetHashCode( );
  }

  /// <summary>Thus and so</summary>
  public override string ToString( )
  {
    return base.ToString( );
  }
}
```

Then, to reference, this works and lights up with all the IDE functionality (except that it doesn't show in the member drop-down):

```
/// <summary>
/// See <see cref="MyStruct.operator=="/>
/// </summary>
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
internal struct BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION
{
   //...
}
```

Go-to functionality works here, too.

**Edit:**

Implicit operator is:

```
<see cref="MyStruct.op_Implicit(int)"
```

Comment: Good catch, that does work indeed! Any thoughts on the conversion operator though?

Comment: @Grx70, I edited the answer...just looked up what the XML output was on the member :-)

Comment: Basing on your answer I've played around with it for a while and posted my findings as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 12):

To elaborate on @Clay's answer - there are two ways (that I know of) of referencing operators in the `<see (...)/>` *XML documentation* tag:

## 1. Using generated method names

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649375/method-names-for-operator-methods-in-c-sharp) for reference.

For the equality operator `bool operator ==(MyStructure x, MyStructure y)` the reference is

```
<see cref="MyStructure.op_Equality(MyStructure, MyStructure)" />
```

For the implicit conversion operator `implicit operator MyStructure(int i)` it is

```
<see cref="MyStructure.op_Implicit(int)" />
```

There is however a drawback to this approach (as far as I can tell). For conversion operators the method names are `op_Implicit` and `op_Explicit` for `implicit` and `explicit` operators respectively. It is possible to have several overloads of these methods differing only by the return type. For instance, for these two operators:

```
public static implicit operator int(MyStructure s) => s.Value;
public static implicit operator double(MyStructure s) => s.Value;
```

these methods will be generated:

```
int op_Implicit(MyStructure)
double op_Implicit(MyStructure)
```

Then this reference:

```
<see cref="MyStructure.op_Implicit(MyStructure)" />
```

will be ambiguous, and it will fallback to whichever operator is defined first. You'll also get a warning saying just that.

## 2. Using *C#* operator names

For the equality operator `bool operator ==(MyStructure x, MyStructure y)` the reference is

```
<see cref="MyStructure.operator ==(MyStructure, MyStructure)" />
```

and for the implicit conversion operator `implicit operator MyStructure(int i)`:

```
<see cref="MyStructure.implicit operator MyStructure(int)" />
```

Obviously there's no problem in disambiguating previously mentioned example:

```
<see cref="MyStructure.implicit operator int(MyStructure)" />
<see cref="MyStructure.implicit operator double(MyStructure)" />
```

## Other considerations

One other difference that I've noticed is that the second approach is properly recognized by *CodeLens*, whereas the first one is not.