# How to properly reference not overloaded operators in documentation?

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

I have a class that overloads the `true`, `false`, `&` and `|` operators, [thus enabling the usage of the `&&` and `||` operators.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#user-defined-conditional-logical-operators)

Everything is working as it should, but I'm having a small problem with the XML documentation of this class.

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40696928/3094533) and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36578459/3094533) I've managed to reference the overloaded operators I've overloaded in the class documentation:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// ...
    /// The ... class overloads the <see cref="op_True"/>, <see cref="op_False"/>, 
    /// <see cref="op_BitwiseAnd"/> and <see cref="op_BitwiseOr"/> 
    /// operators to make it easy to use in validatios.
    /// The <see cref="op_BitwiseAnd"/> operator returns the first failed operand (or the last operand tested),
    /// and the <see cref="op_BitwiseOr"/> operator returns the first succeesfull operand (or the last operand tested).
    /// Since the <see cref="op_True"/>, <see cref="op_False"/> operators 
    /// are also overloaded, &amp;&amp; and || operators can be used to short-circuit.
    /// </summary>
    public class ...
```

Official documentation of the `<see cref="...">` tag states the following:

> The complete set of binary operator function names used is as follows: `op_Addition`, `op_Subtraction`, `op_Multiply`, `op_Division`, `op_Modulus`, `op_BitwiseAnd`, `op_BitwiseOr`, `op_ExclusiveOr`, `op_LeftShift`, `op_RightShift`, `op_Equality`, `op_Inequality`, `op_LessThan`, `op_LessThanOrEqual`, `op_GreaterThan`, and `op_GreaterThanOrEqual`.

From this documentation (as well as my attempts), There's no way to use the `<see cref="...">` for the `&&` and `||` operators (which are `op_LogicalAnd` and `op_LogicalOr` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3016653/3094533)).

So is there a better way than writing them manually into the XML (`&amp;&amp;` and `||`) like I already did?

Comment: Have you tried to use C# operator names from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40696928/4728685)? Also, could you please share the small code sample of overridden operators?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes, I have tried that. No Go. I don't think the code is relevant to the question. It's there, it's working, it's passing all the tests - and it's referenced correctly from the documentation. The question is how to reference the operators that can't be overloaded...